# Dotted background overlay effect in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to achieve the background effect on this website:
http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/home.html

The background pictures seem to be covered in a dotted overlay sort of thing.

Is there a way to create this effect with CSS only?

Comment: The image itself is composed like that.

Comment: see [here](http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo/bg.jpg)

Comment: I see! How come on this site: http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo-3/demo.html  - The image is http://mountaintheme.com/themeforest/mountain/demo-3/images/background2.jpg

Comment: This is an image editing question.

Comment: Well, is there a way to create this effect with CSS only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/Syahrul/1hdousfn/) one way of doing it.

```
<body>
 <div id="overlay">
     image
</div>

<div id="page">
 <div id="content">
  ....
```

Basically, you add a container outside your page container.
Add a fixed position for it, and add a pseudo element :after to it and give it a background image.

Answer (score 18):

A little bit late, but here is a solution that uses just CSS to create the dotted overlay using a pattern created with `radial-gradient`.

```css
.image {
 width: 800px;
 height: 600px;
 position: relative;
 background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Rathong_from_Zemathang2.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
.image:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5);
 background-image: radial-gradient(black 33%, transparent 33%);
 background-size: 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: excellent. if applying to a `<div>` use :before rather than :after to prevent the contained elements from being covered in dots :)

Comment: Man, it's awesome :p Thousands lines in css and i didn't realized that gradient backgrounds can be repeated and sized... Thanks a lot

Comment: Works with `background-size: 3px 3px;` in Chrome, a little blurry in Firefox, doesn't work in IE/Edge.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my way of doing this https://jsfiddle.net/soumyabg/wefLyrhp/

Very minimal and pure CSS solution. The catch is that the actual image is the background of `<a>` tag (with `display:block`), and `<img>` is the dot overlay (its size should be defined in the CSS).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-container">
  <a class="dotm" href="#">
    <img src="http://s14.directupload.net/images/111129/44ga9qid.png" alt="dotm" title="dotm" class="dotm-overlay">
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dotm {
  display: block;
  background: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/SOoaHiWfwZyfu/giphy.gif) no-repeat; /* change with the image URL */
  background-size: cover;
}

.dotm-overlay {
  background: url(http://s14.directupload.net/images/111129/44ga9qid.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px; /*height of the image*/
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this using only css background properties:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(black 50%, transparent 50%);
background-size: 4px 4px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an object with "bg" id, this css class will add small dotted background:

```
#bg {
    background-image: radial-gradient(#000 10%, transparent 10%);
    background-size: 15px 15px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

You can change dots color by replace black (#000) with any color, and background color by replacing #EEE.

To adjust dots size, play with 10% and 15px.